# Binary serial port read missing bytes in c

Tags: c, serial-port

I am sending binary data from an arduino to a serial port where this code is running.
Using cutecom in hex mode can clearly read what I expect on that serial port. As shown below.

```
00000000: 24 04 85 ab 47 43 04 04   24 04 85 ab 47 43 04 04 
00000010: 24 04 85 ab 47 43 04 04   24 04 85 ab 47 43 04 04
```

No problems up to here. I don't believe I need to give the arduino code.

I am trying to read the same thing with c. However the code below only prints this:

```
24 85 ab 47 43 24 85 ab 47 43 24 85 ab 47 43
```

For some reasons it is skipping the 04. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File Control Definitions           */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX Terminal Control Definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX Standard Definitions      */ 
#include <errno.h>   /* ERROR Number Definitions           */
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int open_serial(char *port, int baud);

void main(void)
{
    int tty = open_serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", B115200);
    uint8_t buff[256];   /* Buffer to store the data received              */
    int  n;    /* Number of bytes read by the read() system call */

    while (1) {
        n = read(tty, &buff, sizeof buff); 
        if (n > 0){
            //printf("-%d-\n ", n);
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){   
                printf("%02x ", buff[i]);
            }
            fflush(stdout); 
        }
    }
}

int open_serial(char *port, int baud)
{

    int fd = open( port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);    

    if(fd == -1)                        /* Error Checking */
        printf("\n  Error! in Opening tty  ");

    struct termios SerialPortSettings;  /* Create the structure                          */

    tcgetattr(fd, &SerialPortSettings); /* Get the current attributes of the Serial port */

    /* Setting the Baud rate */
    cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,B115200); /* Set Read  Speed as 115200                       */
    cfsetospeed(&SerialPortSettings,B115200); /* Set Write Speed as 115200                       */

    /* 8N1 Mode */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;   /* Disables the Parity Enable bit(PARENB),So No Parity   */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;   /* CSTOPB = 2 Stop bits,here it is cleared so 1 Stop bit */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;    /* Clears the mask for setting the data size             */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |=  CS8;      /* Set the data bits = 8                                 */

    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;       /* No Hardware flow Control                         */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; /* Enable receiver,Ignore Modem Control lines       */ 


    SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);          /* Disable XON/XOFF flow control both i/p and o/p */
    SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);  /* Non Cannonical mode                            */

    SerialPortSettings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;/*No Output Processing*/

    /* Setting Time outs */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VMIN] = 10; /* Read at least 10 characters */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; /* Wait indefinetly   */


    if((tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings)) != 0) /* Set the attributes to the termios structure*/
        printf("\n  ERROR ! in Setting attributes");
    else
        printf("\n  BaudRate = 115200 StopBits = 1 Parity   = none\n");

    /*------------------------------- Read data from serial port -----------------------------*/

    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);   /* Discards old data in the rx buffer            */
    return fd;
}
```

Comment: I suspect this happens because 0x04 is End Of Transmission (EOT) code.

Comment: Ok. So that means my binary data are interpreted before I access them. How can I disable that to happen?

Comment: 04 has a special meaning, that is "End of Transmission"(See an ASCII table). 

However, most serial monitoring software has settings to change, ignore special characters

Comment: I remember "real term" had display settings

Comment: There are more flags than what you are setting. Instead of copying the old settings with `tcgetattr()`, try starting with a clean struct instead (`memset(&SerialPortSettings, 0, sizeof SerialPortSettings);`

Comment: There is quite a lot of [information here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios).

Comment: In there is a section which contains `// no Ctrl-D suppression` . . . `ONOEOT`. Note that `0x04` is also Ctrl-D.

Comment: About to post the solution. The termios need to be setup in raw mode. I note your memset recommendation Johnny. Weather: It's not 04 specifically that's the issue. It's anything between 0x00 and 0xFF that could be potentially interpreted and not transmitted to the read function. I like the link you sent. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am sending binary data from an arduino to a serial port where this code is running.

Transmission of binary data necessitates that the POSIX serial terminal be configured for non-canonical (aka raw) mode.

> For some reasons it is skipping the 04. Any ideas?

Consistent loss of data that have values in the range of ASCII control characters (i.e. 0x00 through 0x1F) almost always indicates improper termios configuration.
Since the data loss seems to be on the reception side, the first thing to verify is the proper specification of non-canonical input mode.
Your code has

```
SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);  /* Non Cannonical mode                            */
```

The attributes on the right-hand side of the assignment all belong to the `c_lflag` of the termios structure, rather than the `c_iflag` that is coded.
So presumably the default mode of the serial terminal is canonical mode, and your program fails to reconfigure to non-canonical input mode because of this typo.

Your workaround of augmenting your code with a **cfmakeraw()** call is not ideal.
The use of **cfmakeraw()** is convenient for avoiding mistakes like the one you have.
But the buggy statement should be corrected, or even better the operations that are made redundant by the **cfmakeraw()** call can be removed.

```
cfmakeraw() sets the terminal to something like the "raw" mode of the old 
Version 7 terminal driver: input is available character by character, echoing is 
disabled, and all special processing of terminal input and output characters is 
disabled. The terminal attributes are set as follows:

termios_p->c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP
                | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
termios_p->c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
termios_p->c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
termios_p->c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
termios_p->c_cflag |= CS8;
```

---

BTW your code does use the recommended/preferred method of calling **tcgetattr()**, and then setting/modifying the terminal attributes using Boolean operations.  The suggestion of using a *"clean struc"* is not considered portable.

---

**ADDENDUM**

The origin of this **c_iflag** and **ICANON** bug seems to be this [serial port tutorial from xanthium.in](http://xanthium.in/Serial-Port-Programming-on-Linux).  The author was notified back in 2016 of the bug, but has not bothered to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work adding

```
cfmakeraw(&SerialPortSettings);
```

just above the tcsetattr function call.

Comment: You wouldn't need this extra line if instead you corrected the bug in your code: `SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG)` should use `c_lflag` rather than `c_iflag`.

Comment: Nice. Post your answer. I'll tag it as the solution. I pick up that bug from github somewhere.