# Reading uart hex values ignores certain bytes/characters

Tags: c++, redis, serial-port, uart

I'm new to C/C++ and I'm trying to make communication by uart using HEX values.

> Device port: /dev/ttyS2. Baudrate: 38400

I'm using *redis* to subscribe the messages. And for testing I'm using "Termite", a RS232 terminal to simulate.

I found some guide that worked really fine, the problem is that when I try to read the message some bytes/characters mess with it.

Here is my code for the **connection**:

```
    this->fd = open(device,O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    /*---------- Setting the Attributes of the serial port using termios structure --------- */
    tcgetattr(this->fd, &SerialPortSettings);   /* Get the current attributes of the Serial port */

    /* Setting the Baud rate */
    cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,B38400); /* Set Read  Speed as 38400 */
    cfsetospeed(&SerialPortSettings,B38400); /* Set Write Speed as 38400 */

    /* 8N1 Mode */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;   /* Disables the Parity Enable bit(PARENB),So No Parity   */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;   /* CSTOPB = 2 Stop bits,here it is cleared so 1 Stop bit */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;    /* Clears the mask for setting the data size             */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |=  CS8;      /* Set the data bits = 8                                 */

    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;       /* No Hardware flow Control                         */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; /* Enable receiver,Ignore Modem Control lines       */

    SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);          /* Disable XON/XOFF flow control both i/p and o/p */
    SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);  /* Non Cannonical mode                            */

    SerialPortSettings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; /*No Output Processing*/
    SerialPortSettings.c_oflag = 0;

    /* Setting Time outs */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;  /* Read at least X characters */
    SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; /* Wait indefinetly */

    tcflush(this->fd, TCIFLUSH);

    if((tcsetattr(this->fd,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings)) != 0) { /* Set the attributes to the termios structure*/
        printf("\n  ERROR ! in Setting attributes");
    }
    else {
        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &SerialPortSettings);
        printf("\n  BaudRate = 38400 \n  StopBits = 1 \n  Parity   = none\n\n");
    }
```

And here is the code for **reading**:

```
        char read_buffer[32];
        int bytes_read;

        while(true) {
            bytes_read = read(serialport.fd, &read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer)); /* Read the data */

            printf("bytes read: %d", bytes_read);

            if (bytes_read < 0) {
                printf("Error reading: %s", strerror(errno));
            }
            else if (bytes_read > 0) {
                //read_buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';

                printf("\n");
                printf("HEX:");
                for (int i=0; i<bytes_read; i++) {   /*printing only the received characters*/
                    printf(" %02x",read_buffer[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                printf("+----------------------------------+\n");


                /*#if defined(MODULE_REDIS) || defined(MODULE_ALL)
                    //redis.publish("channel:uart:ack", read_buffer);
                    redis.publish("channel:uart:ack", vectorUint8toHex(read_data).c_str());
                #endif*/
            }

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        }
```

When I send the message *0x2401010203040506070809af23*, it only shows 8 bytes. (the bytes *0x03* and *0x04* messes with the message)

```
OUTPUT:

bytes read: 0bytes read: 8
HEX: 05 06 07 08 09 af 23 0a
+----------------------------------+
```

But when I send *0x2401010200000506070809af23*, it works fine

```
OUTPUT:

bytes read: 14
HEX: 24 01 01 02 00 00 05 06 07 08 09 af 23 0a
+----------------------------------+
```

What I'm doing wrong? And one more thing. Using *Termite* have to turn the "append LF" setting or else I can't read the message, but that adds "*0a*" to my message, is this related to the configurations of the serial port?

Comment: Some of the tty flags that get cleared here are cleared from the wrong variables. `ICANON`, and several others, are flags in `c_lflag`, not `c_iflag`. Go over all of these flags, one by one, and verify they're being applied to the correct variable.

Comment: [bytes 0x03 and 0x04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) are "ASCII end of text" and "ASCII end of transmission". Presumably one of your serial port flags does not disable interpretation of those characters.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, when I consulted the ascii table, I think it's working now, I just added "SerialPortSettings.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);" and it works now. My bad, haven't read about flags. It solved boths problems. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary serial port read missing bytes in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556279/binary-serial-port-read-missing-bytes-in-c)

Comment: Yes, I didn't find that. But I already solved, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that some bytes in binary were 0x03 and 0x04 that are in ASCII "end of text" and "end of transmission". And was missing this line on the configurations:

```
SerialPortSettings.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
```

Thanks to the comments, I searched for some missing configurations and found it.

There's another post for my problem that I didn't found at the time:
[Binary serial port read missing bytes in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556279/binary-serial-port-read-missing-bytes-in-c)